# MySQL select post and comment count relative to comment count

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to `select` posts by their comment count like this

```
SELECT id,title
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ci_comments WHERE (post_id = p.id)) AS comment_count
FROM ci_posts p
WHERE type='post' AND active=1
ORDER BY comment_count DESC , date_modified DESC LIMIT 6
```

This works

But I need to filter `comment_count > 10` :

```
SELECT id,title
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ci_comments WHERE (post_id = p.id)) AS comment_count
FROM ci_posts p
WHERE type='post' AND active=1 AND comment_count > 10 
ORDER BY comment_count DESC , date_modified DESC LIMIT 6
```

result :
`Unknown column 'comment_count' in 'where clause'`

So what is the solution  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with having .. having evaul the result of the query

```
SELECT id,title
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ci_comments WHERE (post_id = p.id)) AS comment_count
FROM ci_posts p
WHERE type='post' AND active=1
having comment_count >10
ORDER BY comment_count DESC , date_modified DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Yes Thanks  ... edit [ `omment_count` => `comment_count` ]